# how to get vagrant public key?

Tags: ssh, vagrant

So the issue is that when i do ssh through ip and directly through ssh command, i'm able to login with my key without providing any password, however, when I tries to use ssh command through vagrant and use hostname instead of ip it's asking for password

**Need password**

```
    (venv) dans-test-mbp:public_network dantest$ vagrant ssh host1
vagrant@127.0.0.1's password: 
Last login: Wed Jun 12 16:33:35 2019 from 10.100.174.129
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:26:10:60 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global noprefixroute dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 84345sec preferred_lft 84345sec
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe26:1060/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:9d:49:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.100.172.113/22 brd 10.100.175.255 scope global noprefixroute dynamic eth1
       valid_lft 343545sec preferred_lft 343545sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe9d:4976/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**Don't need Password**

```
(venv) dans-test-mbp:public_network dantest$ ssh vagrant@10.100.172.113
Last login: Wed Jun 12 16:26:10 2019 from 10.0.2.2
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ exit
logout
```

I use this config to create vagrant files:

```
(venv) dans-test-mbp:public_network dantest$ cat Vagrantfile 
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  host_ips = [
    "host1",
    "host2",
    "host3",
    "host4"
  ]

  host_ips.each do |host_name|
      config.vm.define host_name do |host|
        host.vm.box = "centos/7"
        config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)"
        host.vm.synced_folder ".", "/home/vagrant/sync", disabled: true
        host.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
            # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
            vb.memory = "4048"

            # Allow vm to send data via VPN
            vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
        end
      end
  end

end
```

so, I got the issue in my approach, basically, I was overwriting vagrant pub key with my key, thus vagrant was not able to ssh into it but I was. So, now the issue is how do I get vagrant pub key?

Answer (score 1):

You can always pull down vagrant's *default* public key from here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hashicorp/vagrant/master/keys/vagrant.pub

Vagrant will usually replace this key with a "secure" key on boot-up.